# What is the appropriate way to embed another webpage in a site that will send a form?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I am working on a website for a local restaurant. They already have an online ordering platform with another company through their website. However, I would like to embed the online ordering page, possibly with an iframe, on the restaurant's own website so customers can order online without having to go to another website. Personally, I am quite an inexperienced webdev and I'm afraid I will not account for the most secure way to implement this as the customers will be inputting their credit card information through this feature.

Using an iframe to try this, the webpage seems to be fine, visibly. However, what can I do to make sure I won't lose any functionality of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for is click-jacking attacks. The online-ordering system should be configured to **only** allow your site to embed it in an iframe, and your site should not allow any other site to embed your site in an iframe. Look into X-FRAME-OPTIONS and/or Content Security Policy `frame-ancestors`.